# How to get log info to STOP going to console in Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, logging

I have no idea what is causing this but I just did an update and upgrade and now I'm getting all kinds of info going to the terminal.

Here are some simple examples from `sudo` invocation, an anacron, and a simple cron every minute that I implemented to show this.

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: ls
foo
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: sudo ls
 sudo:   drjrm3 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/drjrm3/simpleDir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls
 sudo:   drjrm3 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/drjrm3/simpleDir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by drjrm3(uid=1000)
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by drjrm3(uid=1000)
foo
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:  systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
 anacron[4034]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-07-08
 anacron[4034]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
 CRON[4036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user drjrm3(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
 CRON[4037]: (drjrm3) CMD (echo "Example cron")
 CRON[4036]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
 CRON[4036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user drjrm3
```

Below I have listed (and will continue to list upon request) any information about my system which might help to diagnose or solve this problem. Does anyone have suggestions on what could be causing this or how to fix it?

---

## Details

### 1 - OS / Kernel version

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: uname -r
5.19.0-46-generic
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:
```

### 2 - Kernel log level

AFAIK, this looks correct to me in terms of log level:

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:  cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4   4   1   7
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:
```

### 3 - Reproducible across ssh clients

I am logging in from a Mac and I can reproduce this to the `maeve` workstation in question and can reproduce this behavior across multiple terminal applications.

I also ssh into a raspberry pi from this Mac and the behavior does NOT occur there. However, upon jumping from the rpi to the `maeve`, this behavior presents itself again leading me to believe this is a problem with the workstation setup itself and not any ssh client issue.

### 4 - Reproducibility

After doing some more digging I think it's a `logger` issue. On multiple other machines I can use `logger` and it will not print to the screen. However, on this machine it does.

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: logger hi
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:  drjrm3: hi
```

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@wheems]: logger hi
[drjrm3(BASH)@wheems]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Somehow when I upgraded this line made it into my `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file:

```
drjrm3                          /var/log/drjrm3.log
```

I compared this file with the same path on all my other systems and never saw this line. Based on the documentation for how syslog files should be written (granted, for [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-basic_configuration_of_rsyslog#doc-wrapper)), this did not seem to belong.

As soon as I commented it out and restarted rsyslogd via `sudo service rsyslog restart` I was not able to reproduce the `logger` messages:

```
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: # File just edited.
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: logger foo
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:  drjrm3: foo

[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: logger bar
 drjrm3: bar
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: sudo service rsyslog restart
 sudo:   drjrm3 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/rsyslog.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service rsyslog restart
 sudo:   drjrm3 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/rsyslog.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service rsyslog restart
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by drjrm3(uid=1000)
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by drjrm3(uid=1000)
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: logger foo
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]: logger bar
[drjrm3(BASH)@maeve]:
```